# how to convert the String "http:\/\/www.178.com" to "http://www.178.com" in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to get some URL from a web page. The getted the URL like this:

```
http:\/\/xiaoshuo.360.cn\/novel.html
```

Then I want to connect these urls. The exception will show,since the no valid url.

My question is: how to convert `http:\/\/xiaoshuo.360.cn\/novel.html` to `http://xiaoshuo.360.cn/novel.html`

I try use the `s.replace("\\", "");` and `replaceAll("\\", "");` It doesn't work.

Add the sourcecode:

```
public class GetUrls {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String Url = "http://hao.360.cn/";
    list = getUrls(list, Url);
    if (list.size() < 6000) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            getUrls(list, list.get(i));
        }
    }
}

public static List<String> getUrls(List<String> list, String Url)
        throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL(Url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));
    String str;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (str.contains("http")) {
            String[] strs = str.split("\"");
            for (String s : strs) {
                if (s.startsWith("http")
                        && (s.endsWith("com") | s.endsWith("cn") | s
                                .endsWith("html"))) {
                    s.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
                    System.out.println(s);
                    list.add(s.toString());
                    if (list.size() >= 6000) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (list.size() >= 6000) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return list;
}
}
```

Comment: String str = "http:\/\/www.178.com"; is not valid

Comment: Do you know what `replaceAll` does?

Comment: I had tried it. It doesn't work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but i think it's not valid

Comment: @T.J.Crowder invalid in eclipse.

Comment: @ScaryWombat what in eclipse?does it act different in different ide?

Comment: @fastsnail As per your original comment, the string does not seem to be valid.  it is not valid in my IDE (eclipse)

Comment: @fastsnail It would be invalid if it were in Java source code, but I suspect that OP is telling us the actual contents of the string (which may e.g. be read from a file), not how it would appear in source code.

Comment: Just realized that the body of the question pretty clearly indicates that the string should appear in the source like this, which it can't. Tim, can you clarify your question?

Comment: you could always use a non-replace method i.e. looping through the string. as you are now talking about ascii 92 rather than ascii 27

Comment: @ScaryWombat Do you mean 47? He was always asking about 97, backslashes, as the title shows. No one would ever be trying to strip slashes from URLs.

Comment: When you say, "It doesn't work," what *specifically* doesn't work?

Comment: he wants to keep ascii 47 but stripe backslash (but the backslash is ascii 97) not the esc char

Comment: @David Conrad  I attached the source code.

Comment: You have to assign the result of `replaceAll` or `replace` to some variable. Strings are immutable in Java, so the string doesn't change; instead, it returns a new string in which the replacement has been made. You are ignoring the returned, changed string and continuing to use the old, unchanged one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use regular expressions. If you wish to replace all sequences of a backslash followed by a slash with just a slash, you can use this:

`str = str.replace("\\/", "/");`

The `replace` method replaces all occurrences of one string with another. Because strings are immutable in Java, the method does not alter the string but rather returns a new string with the replacement made.

(Thanks to jhkuperus for pointing out that blinding stripping all backslashes could remove ones which are desired.)

Comment: Maybe use `str.replaceAll("\\\\/","/");`

Comment: @T.J. From the question title, I understood that OP is trying to remove the backslashes from a string. The forward slashes are in OP's code that was attempting but failing to remove them.

Comment: @jhkuperus No, if the string actually contains backslashes followed by forward slashes, and OP only wants the forward slashes, then the solution is to replace the backslashes with nothing, not to replace them with forward slashes. Reread the title of the question.

Comment: @DavidConrad Okay, I guess it depends on his intention. The question itself is ambiguous in that regard. The input and output examples would allow for both scenarios, either remove all backslashes, or just the 'escaped' forward slashes. What if there's a `\"` somewhere in that same string and it has to stay. But it's not in the example given, I agree.

Comment: @jhkuperus On closer reading of the question, I realize that it is pretty confused and ambiguous. I'm thinking of just deleting my answer until OP clarifies.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean there are still backslashes in the string? Or are you trying to do something else with the string, like get the html from that URL, and it doesn't work? What *specifically* does not work?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the @TimWang in my last comment.

Comment: It don't matter @DavidConrad